# While scanning a simple key, could not find expected ':' via FlutterInstall@0 task

Tags: azure-devops

I received an error `/cicd/mobile-publish.yml: (Line: 58, Col: 14, Idx: 1423) - (Line: 58, Col: 14, Idx: 1423): While scanning a simple key, could not find expected ':'.` in the flutter installation task. Moreover, in the Azure DevOps GUI, it refers to an old PR commit from another branch. Interestingly, there is another project and there is the same task, but there are no errors. Despite the error, the pipeline performs the task required of it, nevertheless, when creating a PR, it starts automatically, although it is set to “trigger: none” - which should not be the case

The pipeline code looks like this:
cicd/mobile-publish.yml

```
name: $(Build.BuildId)
trigger: none

parameters:
- name: android
  displayName: Publish Android
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: ios
  displayName: Publish IOS
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: whatsNewEn
  displayName: What's new Eglish
  type: string
- name: whatsNewNo
  displayName: What's new Norwegian
  type: string

jobs:
- job: publish_app
  displayName: Build and publish app
  timeoutInMinutes: 120
  variables:
  - group: some_group_name_1
  - group: some_group_name_2
  pool:
    vmImage: macos-latest
    demands: xcode
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    clean: true
    fetchTags: false
    condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')

  - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
    displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
    inputs:
      provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
      provProfileSecureFile: 'some_secure_file_id'

  - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
    displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
    inputs:
      certSecureFile: 'some_secure_file_id'
      setUpPartitionIdACLForPrivateKey: false

  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    displayName: 'Use Java 11'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 11
      jdkArchitectureOption: x64
      jdkSourceOption: PreInstalled

  - task: FlutterInstall@0
    displayName: Flutter Install
    inputs:
      version: custom      // it is line 58
      customVersion: 3.10.4
```

I found several similar errors on stackoverflow, but there was a syntax problem in the indentation. I checked it myself - everything is ok, compared it with another project - everything is ok, copy-paste from the working project also didn't help. I am hope for your help.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding
`pr: none`

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT, Hi, I tried to do the same as you, I also got the result of successful validation, but it didn’t help, so I just added pr: none

Comment: nice to know that, or you could consider [posting your solution as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), and highlight it to benefit more developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `pr: none` in the

````
name: $(Build.BuildId)
trigger: none
pr: none```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit the task as below, and the validation returned issue-free.

```
- task: FlutterInstall@0
 displayName: Flutter Install
 inputs:
   channel: 'stable'
   version: 'custom'
   customVersion: '3.10.4'
```

[image]

Comment: "I couldn't reproduce the problem you're experiencing" **isn't a solution to the problem**. Don't post an answer that doesn't provide a solution.